# I need help.Which layout I Should use for these pages?

Tags: android

https://www.dropbox.com/s/s7c0dyko9n2zbvx/20131011_163630.jpg
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vpzwqu4f2a6wlhk/20131011_163703.jpg

I am programing an app on android.These photos were taken from İOS.There is a layout which items are listed on the page.How can I create layout like in photos

There is lot of items on db and I kategorized them.When user chose one of them; items will be shown dynimically on 3 column.I don't know how I will use layout in layout ?

Comment: u want to make whole screen or just a one grid layout

Comment: GridLayout with compatibility library as it comes with API14

Comment: There is lot of items on db and I kategorized them.When user chose one of them; items will be shown dynimically on 3 column.I don't know how I will use layout in layout ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use GridLayout in android inside a LinearLayout parent.

Answer (score 0):

Parent layout - `GridLayout` or `TableLayout`, which contains tiles. Each tile - is `LinearLayout` with `ViewPager` and additional `TextView's`.